# Copy annotation form a PDF to another one

Tags: pdf, itext

I need to extract all the annotations in the "pAnnotedFileName" and apply them to the "pOriginalFileName" and save this modification in a new file "pDestinationFileName".

When i'm inspecting the result of vOriginalPage.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS), I see that my document don't have any annotation.  After the put operation when i'm re-inspecting the vOriginalPage.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS) I see that the document have the information, but when i'm opening the new document I don't see any annotation.  I'm trying to do it with iTextSharp.

Any idea of what i'm doing wrong?

There is the code i'm using.

```
private static void CopyAnnotation(string pAnnotedFileName, string pOriginalFileName, string pDestinationFileName)
{
  PdfReader vAnnotedReader = new PdfReader(pAnnotedFileName);
  PdfReader vOriginalReader = new PdfReader(pOriginalFileName);

  Dictionary<int, PdfArray> vAnnotations = new Dictionary<int, PdfArray>();

  for (int vPageNumber = 1; vPageNumber <= vAnnotedReader.NumberOfPages; vPageNumber++)
  {
    PdfDictionary vPage = vAnnotedReader.GetPageN(vPageNumber);

    vAnnotations.Add(vPageNumber, vPage.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS));
  }

  PdfStamper vStamper = new PdfStamper(vOriginalReader, new FileStream(pDestinationFileName, FileMode.Create));

  for (int vPageNumber = 1; vPageNumber <= vOriginalReader.NumberOfPages; vPageNumber++)
  {
    PdfDictionary vOriginalPage = vOriginalReader.GetPageN(vPageNumber);

    var vBeforeAnnotation = vOriginalPage.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

    vOriginalPage.Put(PdfName.ANNOTS, vAnnotations[vPageNumber]);

    var vAfterAnnotation = vOriginalPage.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
  }

  vStamper.Close();

  vAnnotedReader.Close();
  vOriginalReader.Close();
}
```

Thanks